# Extract year from a string using regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column with values that is a string which goes like `"1 2016 Bi-Week"` which can be anything like

```
"2 2016 Bi-Week"

"3 2015 Bi-Week" "22 2014 Bi Week" where 2015,2016 is the year.....
```

I want to extract the year part from this string and compare it with the current year.
How can regular expression help in that way ?

```
col1             col2 col3 
2 2016 Bi-Week   x    67
12 2014 Bi-Week  y    89
22 2013 Bi-Week  z      09
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the database system you are using.

Comment: I am ussing sql developer where i am getting the string in a column.... i hv edited my post

Comment: Matching on `\d{4]` should do the trick, providing that column's values follow a constant format.

Comment: Are you trying to filter the records (column)  by year ?

Comment: yes i have to find it in an sql statement or something

Comment: PeterK matching on \d{4} means ?

Comment: @user3809240 The first few sections of [Regular Expressions Primer](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/regex-intro.html) cover enough to understand `\d{4}`. [Using Regular Expressions in Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm) has Oracle-specific information. *Also*, to reply to someone here and get them notified that you have replied, please use @ in front of their name (as I did at the start of this comment).